# Removing duplicate value in nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'25/10/2020': {'END': '23:45', 'START': '18:00'}, '26/10/2020': {'END': '23:30', 'START': '19:00'}, '27/10/2020': {'END': '19:00', 'START': '19:00'}, '28/10/2020': {'END': '19:00', 'START': '19:00'}, '29/10/2020': {'END': '06:15', 'START': '23:45'}, '29/10/2020_2': {'END': '22:30', 'START': '15:00'}}
```

I want to remove any 'Date' key which has same START and END time.

Expected result:

```
{'25/10/2020': {'END': '23:45', 'START': '18:00'}, '26/10/2020': {'END': '23:30', 'START': '19:00'},  '29/10/2020': {'END': '06:15', 'START': '23:45'}, '29/10/2020_2': {'END': '22:30', 'START': '15:00'}}
```

I've tried removing duplicates with the following code:

```
shifts_for_the_week_no_duplicates = {}
temp = []
for date, time in shifts_for_the_week.items():
    if time not in shifts_for_the_week_no_duplicates.values():
        shifts_for_the_week_no_duplicates[date] = time
```

But as expected this only removes duplicate values as a whole. I am not sure how I can remove wanted values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your data and the expected result, you can try the below code. Hope it helps:

```
data = {'25/10/2020': {'END': '23:45', 'START': '18:00'}, '26/10/2020': {'END': '23:30', 'START': '19:00'}, '27/10/2020': {'END': '19:00', 'START': '19:00'}, '28/10/2020': {'END': '19:00', 'START': '19:00'}, '29/10/2020': {'END': '06:15', 'START': '23:45'}, '29/10/2020_2': {'END': '22:30', 'START': '15:00'}}
result = {}
for date,time in data.items():
    if time['END'] != time['START']:
        result[date] = time

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'25/10/2020': {'END': '23:45', 'START': '18:00'}, '26/10/2020': {'END': '23:30', 'START': '19:00'}, '29/10/2020': {'END': '06:15', 'START': '23:45'}, '29/10/2020_2': {'END': '22:30', 'START': '15:00'}}
```

Update the variable names as per your need.